# Solving a system of linear equations on Isabelle

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, isabelle

I am having problem in representing a system of linear equations on Isabelle/HOL. I suppose I should simply write some  equations jointed by "\and" but I have problem with type declaration for functions (+, *, -), coefficients, variables.

Can somebody help me in clarifying the type declarations for linear equations? In very simple terms and with examples, if possible! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details on what you want to achieve, it is hard to answer.

1. You are reasoning *with* linear equations, then you just write them down (if your variables are of type real, then + has type real => real => real).
2. You are reasoning *about* linear equations, then you need to define a deep embedding of linear equations and an abstract model of them (e.g., you consider them as matrix of coefficients and have a function giving each variable a value and you check that the result matches your expectations).

Distinguishing 1 from 2 is a very basic question. I would recommend reading the prog-prove. While it is not about linear equations, you have the same duality: you can write functions (programs) in Isabelle or define a semantics to reason about functions in Isabelle.

If you are trying to achieve the simpler 1... you need an Isabelle tutorial like the prog-prove.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. First, I simply want to reason with linear equations, by building a system of them and seeing how to calculate its solutions in Isabelle. Then I could try to use the matrix form and doing e.g. Gauss. However, if I simply try to write an equation e.g. a + x - 3 y + z = 2, Isabelle complains stating that "Type unification failed: No type arity fun :: numeral . Type error in application: operator not of function type. Operator:  3 :: ??'a . Operand:   y :: ??'b". The problem is not solved by assigning type real to each item.

Comment: you need to write out multiplication. So 3*y. Otherwise, Isabelle is looking for a function called '3'.